# Setting PKCanvasView to draw on image and save it

Tags: ios, objective-c, pencilkit

**Situation**

In my iOS app, I have a feature where I can take a picture and then, draw on it. I currently use an old `Cocoapods` library and I would like to switch to `PencilKit`.

**Problem**

Documentation and online tutorial are very unclear on the process/result. Is it supported by the framework to draw on an image ? Lots of SO post are saying to put the image in the background with a transparent `PKCanvasView`. that's seems a bit of a hack. Will it support cropping image ?

**What I want**

My goal is to achieve something similar as to what we have when we take a screenshot. An image that you can crop and draw on. Is the post-screenshot UI based on `PencilKit`? How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put an image in the background and draw on by inserting an `UIImageView` as a subview to a `PKCanvasView`:

```
let canvasView = PKCanvasView()
canvasView.isOpaque = true
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil"))
canvasView.insertSubview(imageView, at: 1)
```